# Android SQLite only accepts String[] as whereArgs?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

In my Android app I have an `Event`. An `Event` has as attribute `id` which is a `long` (which identifies the `Event` obviously).

When I want to update an `Event` in the `SQLiteDatabase`, I do the following:

```
sqliteDatabase.delete("events", "id = ?", new String[] { "" + id });
```

It works, but **is there a prettier/more preferred way of doing this?** I mean instead of creating a new `String[]` for only one element and wrapping the long to a `String`, which is cumbersome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It works, but is there a prettier/more preferred way of doing this?

Use `String.valueOf(id)` instead of `""+id`, as it will run faster and create less garbage.

> I mean instead of creating a new String[] for only one element and wrapping the long to a String, which is cumbersome.

You are welcome to write your own method that hides the cumbersome-osity from the rest of your code.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [PreparedStatement](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and bind your variable to it. But this requires you to write an accusal SQL-Query.

Comment: +1 for the alternative solution, but I think that would be even more cumbersome considering you'd have to prepare the statement, then bind the arguments, thanks though.

Comment: If you do more then one query with the same SQL-Syntax but other values, a prepared statement is a lot faster and it's save against SQL-Injections.

Answer (score 1):

Not a java coder, but maybe this works?

```
sqliteDatabase.delete("events", "id = ?", { id.toString() });
```

Comment: It's not that it doesn't work, he simply doesn't want to create a new String-array with only one element in it.

Comment: Also, I don't think that is possible in Java. (Just the { } for arrays)

Comment: @Whirlwin It is possible: `String[] test = {"Halo", "World"};` <- This should compile and run just fine.

Comment: I know, but I meant as an argument. Can't edit the comment anymore.